# App won't stay in Portrait mode in Trigger.io

Tags: iphone, ios, trigger.io

Running an app in iOS6 right now and it won't stay in landscape mode for iPhone/iPad devices. I've checked the docs and other-related questions but can't find an answer. I believe we're following the docs, so, maybe we've got some incorrect formatting. Here's the config, which I've only stripped out identifying/key/hash info:

```
{
    "config_version": "2",
    "name": "appname",
    "author": "author-email",
    "version": "0.1",
    "platform_version": "v1.4.50",
    "description": "description goes here",
    "partners": {
        "parse": {
            "applicationId": "id",
            "clientKey": "clientkeyishere",
            "parseRestKey": "parsekey"
        }
    },
    "modules": {
        "requirements": {
            "ios": {
                "minimum_version": "4.3",
                "device_family": "iphone"
            }
        },
        "icons": {
            "android": {
                "36": "res/icons/android/ldpi.png",
                "48": "res/icons/android/mdpi.png",
                "72": "res/icons/android/hdpi.png",
                "96": "res/icons/android/xhdpi.png"
            },
            "ios": {
                "57": "res/icons/ios/icon_iphone@1x.png",
                "72": "res/icons/ios/icon_ipad@1x.png",
                "114": "res/icons/ios/icon_iphone@2x.png",
                "144": "res/icons/ios/icon_ipad@2x.png",
                "512": "res/icons/ios/icon_512.png"
            }
        },
        "launchimage": {
            "iphone": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash@1x.png",
            "iphone-retina": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash@2x.png",
            "iphone-retina4": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash_iphone_tall.png",
            "ipad": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash_ipad_tall@1x.png",
            "ipad-landscape": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash_ipad_wide@1x.png",
            "ipad-retina": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash_ipad_tall@2x.png",
            "ipad-landscape-retina": "res/splash/ios/siren_splash_ipad_wide@1x.png",
            "android": "res/splash/android/android_logo.png",
            "android-landscape": "res/splash/android/android_logo.png",
            "background-color": "#000000"
        },
        "package_names": {
            "ios": "packagenameishere"
        },
        "display": {
            "orientation": {
                "default": "portrait",
                "iphone": "portrait",
                "ipad": "portrait",
                "android": "portrait"
            }
        },
        "geolocation": true,
        "logging": {
            "level": "DEBUG"
        },
        "request": {
            "permissions": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ]
        },
        "contact": true,
        "file": true,
        "is": true,
        "media": {},
        "prefs": true,
        "tools": true,
        "reload": true,
        "parameters": {
            "api": "apigoeshere"
        }
    },
    "plugins": {
        "rate": {
            "hash": "hashishere",
            "type": "project"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this formatting, I think it changes from time to time.
This is with Toolkit v2.0.1
Works for me.

```
{
    "modules": {
        "display": {
            "config": {
                "orientations": {
                    "android": "portrait",
                    "ipad": "portrait",
                    "iphone": "portrait"
                }
            },
            "version": "2.2"
         }
    }
}
```

Full example from my working config:

```
{
"author": "",
"config_version": "4",
"core": {
    "general": {
        "reload": true
    },
    "ios": {
        "device_family": "iphone",
        "minimum_version": "4.3",
        "package_name": ""
    }
},
"description": "",
"homepage": "",
"modules": {
    "contact": {
        "disabled": true,
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    "display": {
        "config": {
            "orientations": {
                "android": "portrait",
                "ipad": "portrait",
                "iphone": "portrait"
            }
        },
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    "file": {
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    "flurry": {
        "config": {
            "ios_api_key": ""
        },
        "version": "2.3",
        "disabled": true
    },
    "geolocation": {
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "icons": {
        "config": {
            "ios": {
                "57": "assets/graphic/icons/icon-57.png",
                "72": "assets/graphic/icons/icon-72.png",
                "76": "assets/graphic/icons/AppIcon76x76.png",
                "114": "assets/graphic/icons/icon-114.png",
                "120": "assets/graphic/icons/AppIcon60x60@2x.png",
                "144": "assets/graphic/icons/icon-144.png",
                "152": "assets/graphic/icons/AppIcon76x76@2x.png",
                "512": "assets/graphic/icons/icon-512.png",
                "prerendered": true
            }
        },
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    "launchimage": {
        "config": {
            "ios": {
                "1536x2048": "assets/graphic/splash/1536x2048-splash.png",
                "320x480": "assets/graphic/splash/320x480-splash.png",
                "640x1136": "assets/graphic/splash/640x1136-splash.png",
                "2048x1536": "assets/graphic/splash/2048x1536-splash.png",
                "1536x2008": "assets/graphic/splash/1536x2008-splash.png",
                "1024x768": "assets/graphic/splash/1024x768-splash.png",
                "2048x1496": "assets/graphic/splash/2048x1496-splash.png",
                "1024x748": "assets/graphic/splash/1024x748-splash.png",
                "640x960": "assets/graphic/splash/640x960-splash.png",
                "768x1004": "assets/graphic/splash/768x1004-splash.png",
                "768x1024": "assets/graphic/splash/768x1024-splash.png"
            }
        },
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    "media": {
        "config": {},
        "disabled": true,
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    "notification": {
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    "parse": {
        "config": {
            "applicationId": "",
            "clientKey": ""
        },
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "prefs": {
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "request": {
        "config": {
            "permissions": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ]
        },
        "version": "2.3"
    },
    "sms": {
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "tabbar": {
        "disabled": true,
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    "tabs": {
        "version": "2.4"
    },
    "urlhandler": {
        "config": {
            "scheme": ""
        },
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "topbar": {
        "version": "2.2"
    }
},
"name": "",
"platform_version": "v2.0.1",
"version": ""
}
```